# Trying to get character input at specific line

Tags: java, char, do-while

I'm working on a program that'll eventually calculate currency transfer but I'm already stuck. I'm getting the "Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at Currency.main(Currency.java:31)".
```

So I know it happens at line (31) and I have a somewhat idea of what the problem is. I think it's because I already got the user's input when I'm asking for the exchange rate of Euros, Pounds, and Yen. My teacher kinda just threw this at us without really teaching us character inputs. My question is how do I get the program to read the 4th input from the program to go towards the loop. Thanks in advance!

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Currency
    {
     public static void main(String[]args)
     {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int quitInput = 0;

        System.out.println("How many Euros a dollar will buy?");
        double euros = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many Pound Sterling a dollar will buy?");
        double pound = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many Yen a dollar will buy?");
        double yen = input.nextDouble();

        do {
                System.out.println("Enter 'E' to buy Euros, 'P' to buy Pound Sterling, 'Y' to buy yen, or 'Q' to quit");
                String decisionString = input.nextLine();
                char decision = decisionString.charAt(0);

                if (decision == 'E' || decision == 'e')
                {
                 System.out.println("Euros");
                }
                else if (decision == 'P' || decision == 'p')
                {
                 System.out.println("Pound Sterling");
                }
                else if (decision == 'Y' || decision == 'y')
                {
                 System.out.println("Yen");
                }
                else if (decision == 'Q' || decision == 'q')
                {
                 System.out.println("Are you sure you want to quit?");
                 String quit = input.nextLine();
                 char exit = quit.charAt(0);
                 if (exit == 'Y' || exit == 'y')
                 {
                  quitInput = -1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  quitInput = 1;
                 }
                }
                else
                {
                 System.out.println("Your input was invalid, please try again \n");
                }
         }      while (quitInput >= 0);

                System.out.println("End");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

```
double yen = input.nextDouble();
```

It will only consume the `double` not the `new line` so by the time you call the `String decisionString = input.nextLine();` it will then consume the new line thus giving you error.

**solution:**

call `nextLine` after `nextDouble` to consume the newLine

```
double yen = input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an empty line because `nextDouble()` just reads the `double` and not the enter after it. Easiest solution I can think of is calling `input.nextLine()` after that line.

```
double yen = input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to skip the carriage return of your nextXXX() calls.

nextDouble() does not reads the next line. So you will face error when you will take input for decision (both currency as well as quit character). here is the fix for your program.

> Replace nextLine() with next().

import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Currency
    {
     public static void main(String[]args)
     {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int quitInput = 0;

    System.out.println("How many Euros a dollar will buy?");
    double euros = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many Pound Sterling a dollar will buy?");
    double pound = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many Yen a dollar will buy?");
    double yen = input.nextDouble();

    do {
            System.out.println("Enter 'E' to buy Euros, 'P' to buy Pound Sterling, 'Y' to buy yen, or 'Q' to quit");
            String decisionString = input.next();
            char decision = decisionString.charAt(0);

            if (decision == 'E' || decision == 'e')
            {
             System.out.println("Euros");
            }
            else if (decision == 'P' || decision == 'p')
            {
             System.out.println("Pound Sterling");
            }
            else if (decision == 'Y' || decision == 'y')
            {
             System.out.println("Yen");
            }
            else if (decision == 'Q' || decision == 'q')
            {
             System.out.println("Are you sure you want to quit?");
             String quit = input.next();
             char exit = quit.charAt(0);
             if (exit == 'Y' || exit == 'y')
             {
              quitInput = -1;
             }
             else
             {
              quitInput = 1;
             }
            }
            else
            {
             System.out.println("Your input was invalid, please try again \n");
            }
     }      while (quitInput >= 0);

            System.out.println("End");
   } 
}
```